# Can you identify this plane?

Tags: aviation-history

Can you identify this plane?

[image: Unknown airplane]

Unknown airplane

I have just found the photo on a CD together with many other planes and helicopters. I have no clue regarding the place where the picture was taken, the time and the type of the plane.

Comment: Google reverse image search seems to think it's a IAR 80, but someone who knows more than I would need to confirm.

Comment: Roddy, I had no idea Google has such a feature. This is amazing. I have tried, in the meantime, with another 2 planes and Google found them immediately. Thank you very much.

Comment: IAR 81C according to this page: [The IAR-81 fighter-bomber](http://www.geocities.ws/huzumstreza/IAR-81.htm) (same tail number).

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to a very interesting plane :)

Comment: @mins, that indeed appears to be a cleaner scan of the same photograph.

Answer (score 8):

@Roddy is correct. It is an Romanian [IAR-80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAR_80) all right.

[image: IAR-80]

"[IAR80](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IAR80.jpg#/media/File:IAR80.jpg)" by user:Planck -  [licensing policy](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Licensing).. Licensed under Public Domain via [Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

IAR-80 was produced by IAR (Intreprinderea Aeronautică Română), an airplane manufacturer that was the property of the Romanian State until the end of the WWII. The aircraft first flew in 1938 and was in service till 1952.

The model appears to be the IAR 81. The same image can be found [here](http://avia-museum.narod.ru/romania/iar-80.html). It was probably taken in the eastern front.